# "Мне 32" или "Мне — 32"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Речь о возрасте. Как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Предложение неполное, стиль разговорный. Лучше перейти на буквенную запись.

**Мне тридцать два.** Это просто сообщение о возрасте, может быть ответом на вопрос.

**Мне ― тридцать два.** Делается пауза, логически выделено местоимение. Это уже открытие темы с необходимыми комментариями: что следует из этого факта, что вы думаете о своем возрасте.